# Configuration error on WCF sqlBinding

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, biztalk

I've received a .NET solution that needs to be integrated into a new website. The solution contains a single WCF service that feeds a Google Maps map. However, I'm not able to get it up and running. There is a dependency on a SQL binding, but I cannot figure out what exactly I need to install to make this work. The Web.config file has a reference to a `SqlAdapterBinding` which has a `enableBizTalkCompatiblity` attribute. Which version of Microsoft BizTalk do I need to install?

```
<bindings>
  <sqlBinding>
    <binding 
        name="SqlAdapterBinding" 
        maxConnectionPoolSize="100" 
        encrypt="false" 
        workstationId="" 
        useAmbientTransaction="true" 
        batchSize="20" 
        polledDataAvailableStatement="" 
        pollingStatement="" 
        pollingIntervalInSeconds="30" 
        pollWhileDataFound="false" 
        notificationStatement="" 
        notifyOnListenerStart="true" 
        enableBizTalkCompatibilityMode="true" 
        chunkSize="4194304" 
        inboundOperationType="Polling" 
        useDatabaseNameInXsdNamespace="false" 
        allowIdentityInsert="false" 
        acceptCredentialsInUri="false" 
        enablePerformanceCounters="false" 
        xmlStoredProcedureRootNodeName="" 
        xmlStoredProcedureRootNodeNamespace="" />
  </sqlBinding>
</bindings>
```

The error being thrown is a configuration error:

**Description:** An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

**Parser Error Message:** Configuration binding extension `system.serviceModel/bindings/sqlBinding` could not be found. Verify that this binding extension is properly registered in system.serviceModel/extensions/bindingExtensions and that it is spelled correctly.

This is thrown on the configuration line saying `<sqlBinding>`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need full BizTalk Server to use the WCF sqlBinding.

You can download it on it's own from here:  [Microsoft BizTalk Adapter for SQL Server](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=333)

The enableBizTalkCompatibility flag tells the binding to forward some BizTalk specific properties, which you would not use.  Set that to false.

Comment: That adapter still needs the WCF LOB Adapter SDK to be installed. I've fixed it by downloading the BizTalk 2013R2 Evaluation and only installing the tools part. That seems to work.

Comment: NO!  You can download the WCF LOB Adapter SDK from here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22067

Comment: You cannot use the BizTalk Media since the license will expire and it may even time-out.